# Error in RStudio: could not find function "%>%"

Tags: r

I'm running a code in R in order to obtain a graphic of Gross domestic product (gdp) VS gini coefficient, but code produces an error:

```
names<-c("Antofagasta","Tarapaca","Arica y Parinacota")
gini<-c(0.439,0.429,0.425)
gdp<-c(24626,6215,2139)
economic_values<-data.frame(names=names,gini=gini,gdp_per_capita=gdp)
economic_values
economic_values%>%ggplot()+geom_point(aes(x = gdp_per_capita, y = gini))
```

**Error: could not find function "%>%"**

Comment: `library(magrittr)` or `library(dplyr)` would fix the error.

Comment: `library(tidyverse)` and `library(dslabs)` fixed the error, thanks